# Create a dict of lists

Tags: python, python-2.6

Hopefully I've explained it well enough in the title but here is what I have:

Input data:

```
Mushroom Kingdom, Mario

Hyrule, Link

Mushroom Kingdom, Bowser

Zebes, Samus

Zebes, Metroid
```

And I want to run something like this,

```
# The next three lines establish that I'll be reading proc as a file
import subprocess
cmd = 'external command that returns the above data'
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

homeworlds = {}

while True:
  line = proc.stdout.readline().split(',')
  if line:
    # If line isn't empty
    homeword = line[0]
    person = line[1]

    homeworlds[homeword] = list.append[person] # Good logic? Bad syntax?

  else:
   break
```

The goal is that I'll be able to call:

```
print homeworlds['Mushroom Kingdom']
```

and return the list

```
Mario, Bowser
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 if not homeword in homeworlds:
    homeworlds[homeword] = list()
 homeworlds[homeword].append(person)
```

Comment: homeworlds.append(person) -> homeworlds[homeword].append(person)

Comment: Better solution is using collections.defaultdict()

Comment: Could someone elaborate as to why defaultdict is a better option here?

Answer (score 2):

It's easier to use a [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) here. Also, you're curretnly calling `split()` without any parameters. What you really want to do is split on the `,`. So you should call `split(',')`.

So your code should look somewhat like this:

```
homeworlds = collections.defaultdict(list)
while True:
  line = proc.stdout.readline().split(',')
  if line:
    # If line isn't empty
    homeworld = line[0].strip()
    person = line[1].strip()

    homeworlds[homeworld].append(person)

  else:
    break
```

Comment: You might want `homeworld = line[0].strip()` (etc.) since splitting on `','` will leave whitespace on the ends of the string.

Comment: Could you explain why defaultdict is the best choice?

Comment: It's lighter to program with. You don't have to check for the presence of a key. If the key does not exist in the dictionary, it will create the key as well as (in this case) an empty list as the value of that key. So you don't have to do `if myKey in myDict: myDict[myKey].append(...); else: myDict[myKey] = [...]`. Rather you can do `myDict[myKey].append(...)` directly, even if `myKey` is not in `myDict`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if homeword not in homeworlds:
    homeworlds[homeword] = []
homeworlds[homeword].append(person)
```

This checks to see if there's an entry for `homeword` in `homeworld`.  If there's not, it adds a list there.  Then we know for sure that we have a list at `homeworld[homeword]` so we can just call `.append(person)` on it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict
homeworlds = defaultdict(list)

homeworlds[homeword].append(person)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a consistant and elegant solutions (partially inspired from other answers) :

```
#!/bin/env python
from collections import defaultdict

lines = """Mushroom Kingdom, Mario

Hyrule, Link

Mushroom Kingdom, Bowser

Zebes, Samus

Zebes, Metroid
"""

homeworlds = defaultdict(list)

for line in lines.splitlines():
    if line and ',' in line:
        key, value = line.split(',')
        homeworlds[key].append(value.trim())

print(homeworlds)
```

Comment: Note that `line.split(', ')` will split on every occurence of the string `', '`, so this probably isn't quite what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
Python 2.7.3rc2 (default, Apr 22 2012, 22:30:17) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> input_data = [('Mushroom Kingdom', 'Mario'),
...  ('Hyrule', 'Link'),
...  ('Mushroom Kingdom', 'Bowser'),
...  ('Zebes', 'Samus'),
...  ('Zebes', 'Metroid')]
>>> homeworlds = {}
>>> for homeword,person in input_data:
...   homeworlds.setdefault(homeword, []).append(person)
... 
>>> homeworlds
{'Hyrule': ['Link'], 'Zebes': ['Samus', 'Metroid'], 'Mushroom Kingdom': ['Mario', 'Bowser']}
>>> print(homeworlds['Mushroom Kingdom'])
['Mario', 'Bowser']
>>> print("{0}".format(', '.join(homeworlds['Mushroom Kingdom'])))
Mario, Bowser
```

in your case swap in for loop: 'input_data' for 'line'